# Why Styled- components doesn´t work in react

Tags: reactjs, importerror, styled-components

I try to use styled-component in react but I am always getting error

```
Failed to compile.

./src/Components/Header/style.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'styled-components' in 'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\luna\src\Components\Header'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\DumpStack.log.tmp'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\pagefile.sys'
Error from chokidar (C:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'C:\swapfile.sys'
```

My Header.js

```
import React from 'react';
import {HeaderStyle} from './style';

const Header =()=>{
    return(
        <HeaderStyle>
            <div className="Header">
                <h1>Luna</h1>
            </div>
        </HeaderStyle>
    )
}

export default Header ;
```

style.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";

export const HeaderStyle = styled.section`
    background-color:black;
`
```

Do you have any ideas why It doesn´t work?

Comment: This may sound trivial, but, did you install the library? In that case, does it appear in the `package.json`?

Comment: Can you try installing the library again: `npm install styled-components`